# How to skip return in ramda if condition is false?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

So I need to replace two javascript if statements with ramda, they look like this:

```
 if (!is(String, name)) {
      return target[name]
    }
    if (includes(name, reserved)) {
      return target[name]
    }
```

It's part of a Proxy object, and after these if statements there's the rest of the code. I tried to do it in Ramda like this:

```
const target = path('target', 'name')
const isDefault = anyPass([!is(String), includes(reserved)])
return unless(isDefault, target)(name)
```

But this way the code after return statement is unreachable, unlike with usual if statements, how can I write it in Ramda without returning in place?